# W3C - document type does not allow element "a" here

Tags: javascript, xhtml, w3c

i have been trying to validate my website codes by W3C in XHTML 1.0 Strict.

My last error i cant fix for now:

```
"document type does not allow element "a" here"
```

it is because i have been "hiding" email address from robots by this code:

```
<td><script type="text/javascript">var name="contact";var domain="theriff.fr";document.write('<a href="mail'+'to:'+name+'@'+domain+'">&#x63;&#x6F;&#x6E;&#x74;&#x61;&#x63;&#x74;&#x40;&#x74;&#x68;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x66;&#x66;&#x2E;&#x66;&#x72;</a>');</script></td>
```

Does anyone know how i could keep email address kinda "hidden" as it is, and still validate that last error in W3C please?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using XHTML instead of HTML 4.01 strict or HTML5?

Comment: no idea at all to be honest, and old habit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the XML parser it looks like you have an `<a>` element inside a `<script>` element (the parser doesn't understand JavaScript).

Declare a [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) inside the `<script>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        // JavaScript here
    // ]]>
</script>
```

This tells the parser to not parse (i.e. interpret as XML) what's inside the CDATA section. The `//` before the delimiters might be necessary to prevent the JS engine from interpreting them if the browser passes them along to the JS engine.

See also: [Properly Using CSS and JavaScript in XHTML Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents).

---

**Side note:** [You can't use `document.write` in XHTML documents:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes)

> Note: `document.write` (like `document.writeln`) does not work in XHTML documents (you'll get a "Operation is not supported" (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR) error on the error console). This is the case if opening a local file with a .xhtml file extension or for any document served with an application/xhtml+xml MIME type. More information is available in the [W3C XHTML FAQ](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite).

Comment: Perfect and quick answer thank you :) *edit fixed // i see ^^* thanks again

Comment: @Pyro: One has to wait 15 min after asking a question before accepting any answer.

Comment: Never had any error of that type and using javascript and XHTML type for years now :/ im lost lol

Comment: @user3916429 XHTML usually isn't.  Unless you send the right document type down with the HTML headers, the browser is going to assume that you really are using HTML anyways, which means that it will read your XHTML as simply weird and badly written HTML.  Browsers are *really good* at making sense out of badly written pages, otherwise the entire internet would break.

Comment: yea i understand, but i guess with this it is supposed to know it is XHTML at least, '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'